# Traveling from USA to India via Australia (unstamped H-1B)

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, australia, tourist-visas, h1b-visas

I'm an Indian passport holder, currently in the US on the H-1B. My first H-1B expired, and I've renewed/extended it already. I have all the documents I need from the USCIS and I'm going to be headed to India to get it stamped.

Seeing as I'm way overdue for a vacation, and Australia's on my bucket list, I'd like to spend a couple of weeks in Australia on the way over. Does anyone have any experience with doing something similar? I'll be traveling sometime in May 2017. I'm assuming I need to apply for the "Visitor visa (subclass 600)". Are they likely to look sideways at the unstamped H-1B? I'll have a ticket headed from Australia to India, and then India to the USA beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any experience with doing something similar?

On its own would, IMO, be [too broad](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3900/is-asking-for-personal-experience-on-topic-and-if-not-under-what-category-is-i)

> Are they likely to look sideways at the unstamped H-1B?

No. What counts is that (a) you have the requisite Australian visa, (b) outbound from USA, you hold a passport for your destination after Australia and (c) on the way back you have a valid visa for USA.